# Illegal Monitor Exception in Reentrant lock

Tags: java, multithreading, buffer, monitor

I have a java class that contains a array list and acting like a buffer
on the other hand i have a publisher that I do not want to create new data after the buffer is full and have to wait for the subscriber to be empty.

my buffer class:

```
private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private Condition notFull = lock.newCondition();
private Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();

public int take() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            int item = integers.remove(0);
            notFull.signal();
            return item;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void put(int item) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            while (isFull()) notFull.await();
            integers.add(item);
            notEmpty.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

and after that my publisher class

```
private Condition notFull;
private Condition notEmpty;

public Publisher(Buffer buffer) {
    this.instance_id = aLong.getAndIncrement();
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.notFull = buffer.getNotFull();
    this.notEmpty = buffer.getNotEmpty();
}

public void run() {
        String threadName = "Publisher_Thread_" + this.instance_id;
        Thread.currentThread().setName(threadName);
        Random random = new Random();

        while(true) {
            try {
                while (buffer.isFull()) notFull.await();
                int item = random.nextInt(1, 10);
                this.buffer.put(item);
                System.out.println(threadName + " added " + item);
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000, 2000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

but i catch the java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException exception

Comment: Don't have time to give a proper answer, but I'm guessing that the problem is in the `Publisher.run()` method where it calls `notFull.await()`.  The `await()` call probably is throwing the exception because `lock` is not locked. See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.